# WHERE clause with CASE not recognizing the second case condition

Tags: mysql

The below Case Clause I am using in an inner Join as a WHERE condition on MAX value id, the Case query is only giving me results as per the first condition > lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL THEN lasteditor != "abc@example.com".

What I wish to do is, if lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NULL then use lasteditor = "abc@example.com" else ignore abc@example.com as lasteditor and get the next lasteditor email

```
                WHERE 
                    CASE WHEN 
                        lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL
                            THEN
                                lasteditor != "abc@example.com"
                    WHEN
                        lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NULL
                            THEN 
                                lasteditor = "abc@example.com"

                    ELSE NULL END
```

What I am trying to do is, inner join on latest Rows where the LastEditor is anything but abc@example.com, however, if there is no result at all if the LastEditor is not abc@example.com, then get the row with abc@example.com

```
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid,dyna_id,LastEditor FROM t2

        WHERE 
                CASE WHEN t2.lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL
                    THEN t2.lasteditor != "abc@example.com"
                    WHEN t2.lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NULL
                    THEN t2.lasteditor = "abc@example.com"

                    ELSE NULL END

    GROUP BY t2.dyna_id) AS history ON main.id = history.dyna_id
```

Summary

```
                WHERE t2.lasteditor = (CASE
                WHEN t2.lasteditor != 'abc@example.com' --- if rows exists --- THEN 'abc@example.com' (if rows exists after skipping rows where lasteditor is abc@example.com then use this case)
                WHEN t2.lasteditor != 'abc@example.com' --- if no rows exists --- THEN pick up the rows where 'abc@example.com' is the last editor
                END)
```

The below code did it, i guess it did, its a huge table I am working on, I hope it is showing the right results

```
                    WHERE
                        CASE
                            WHEN
                            lasteditor <> "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL
                            THEN
                                lasteditor <> "abc@example.com"
                                ELSE
                                lasteditor <> "test"
                            END
                            GROUP BY
                            hist.dyna_id
```

Full Query below

```
            SELECT
               "Total",
               COUNT(IF(main.case_status = "OPEN", 1, NULL)) AS "open_cases",
               COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TM" 
                     AND main.tm_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.tm_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tm_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TL" 
                     AND main.tl_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.tl_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tl_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE2" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "bb", COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TM" 
                     AND main.tm_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.tm_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tm_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TL" 
                     AND main.tl_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.tl_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tl_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE2" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "mb", COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TM" 
                     AND main.tm_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.tm_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tm_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TL" 
                     AND main.tl_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.tl_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tl_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE2" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "tb", COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "na" 
                  THEN
                     main.id 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "na" 
            FROM
               gt AS main 
               LEFT JOIN
                  frontend_forms_users AS caseowner 
                  ON main.se_v_9 = caseowner.alias 
               INNER JOIN
                  (
                     SELECT
                        MAX(id) AS maxid,
                        dyna_id AS dn 
                     FROM
                        history_gt hist 
                     WHERE
                        CASE
                           WHEN
                              lasteditor <> "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN
                              lasteditor <> "abc@example.com" 
                           ELSE
                              lasteditor <> "test" 
                        END
                     GROUP BY
                        hist.dyna_id 
                  )
                  AS history 
                  ON main.id = dn 
               LEFT JOIN
                  history_gt AS owner2 
                  ON maxid = owner2.id 
               LEFT JOIN
                  frontend_forms_users AS owner 
                  ON owner2.LastEditor = owner.primary_email 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
               caseowner.attr_lob AS lob,
               COUNT(IF(main.case_status = "OPEN", 1, NULL)) AS "open_cases",
               COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TM" 
                     AND main.tm_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.tm_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tm_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TL" 
                     AND main.tl_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.tl_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tl_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE2" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "0 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "3 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "bb", COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TM" 
                     AND main.tm_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.tm_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tm_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TL" 
                     AND main.tl_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.tl_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tl_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE2" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "2 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "5 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "mb", COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TM" 
                     AND main.tm_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.tm_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tm_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "TL" 
                     AND main.tl_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.tl_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.tl_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "SE2" 
                     AND main.owner_perception > "4 Star" 
                     AND main.owner_perception < "6 Star" 
                  THEN
                     main.owner_perception 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "tb", COUNT( 
               CASE
                  WHEN
                     owner.attr_role = "na" 
                  THEN
                     main.id 
                  ELSE
                     NULL 
               END
            ) AS "na" 
            FROM
               gt AS main 
               LEFT JOIN
                  frontend_forms_users AS caseowner 
                  ON main.se_v_9 = caseowner.alias 
               INNER JOIN
                  (
                     SELECT
                        MAX(id) AS maxid,
                        dyna_id AS dn 
                     FROM
                        history_gt hist 
                     WHERE
                        CASE
                           WHEN
                              lasteditor <> "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN
                              lasteditor <> "abc@example.com" 
                           ELSE
                              lasteditor <> "test" 
                        END
                     GROUP BY
                        hist.dyna_id 
                  )
                  AS history 
                  ON main.id = dn 
               LEFT JOIN
                  history_gt AS owner2 
                  ON maxid = owner2.id 
               LEFT JOIN
                  frontend_forms_users AS owner 
                  ON owner2.LastEditor = owner.primary_email 
            GROUP BY
               lob 
            ORDER BY
               2 DESC
```

Comment: `WHEN lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NOT NULL` : this is not valid SQL. What check are you trying to implement ?

Comment: `THEN lasteditor != "abc@example.com"` : not valid SQL as well

Comment: It is impossible to understand. I really tried

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL accepts `"` for string literals but you should never use them like that. Use single quotes, that's the proper way to do it in SQL. Also instead of `!=` it's more common to use `<>`.

Comment: Provide **sample data** and **expected result** THEN we might understand. (don't use images please)  this may help: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ **ADD** this information **to the question** (there is an edit link for this)

Comment: When `lasteditor != "abc@example.com" IS NULL` that follows, that `lasteditor` has to be null, since it's the only not literal expression in there and the literals aren't null. But when `lasteditor` is null `lasteditor = "abc@example.com"` will be null too, not `1` or `0`. So your second branch makes no sense. Edit your question and include a minimized example of what you're trying to to. Post tables structure as `CREATE TABLE` statements, provide sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data. Comprehensively explain how the input and output are related.

Comment: I would post your full context of the query showing the from tables as well.

Comment: Are you still seeking he solution? Below I have now supplied 4 possible approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a scenario that might help. The main table is articles with an author and against any article can be comment by the author or anyone else. I just want to display the most recent comment by anyone that is not the author, *unless only the author has commented*.

**EDIT**

**To display the most recent comment by anyone that is not the author - except if there is only author comments, then get the latest author comment.**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE article(
>    id     INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>   ,author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
>   ,title  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO article(id,author,title)
> VALUES 
>   (1,'abc@example.com','a first article')
> , (2,'def@example.com','beware of between')
> , (3,'ghi@example.com','to be or not whatever');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE comments(
>    id         INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>   ,article_id INTEGER  NOT NULL
>   ,author     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
>   ,body VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO comments(id,article_id,author,body) 
> VALUES
>   (1,1,'abc@example.com','first comment')
> , (2,1,'def@example.com','second comment')
> , (3,1,'ghi@example.com','third comment')
> , (4,1,'abc@example.com','2nd author comment')
> , (5,3,'ghi@example.com','only comment')
> ;
> ```

**Correlated Query** approach (any MySQL version) works via by the `order by case when c.author <> t.author then 1 else 2 end, id DESC` and `limit`

> ```
> select
>       a.*
>     , c.*
> from (
>     select
>            t.*
>          , (select id 
>             from comments as c 
>             where c.article_id = t.id 
>             order by
>                   case when c.author <> t.author then 1 else 2 end
>                 , id DESC
>             limit 1) AS max_comment_id
>     from article as t
>     ) a
> left join comments as c on a.max_comment_id = c.id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | author          | title                 | max_comment_id |   id | article_id | author          | body         
> -: | :-------------- | :-------------------- | -------------: | ---: | ---------: | :-------------- | :------------
>  1 | abc@example.com | a first article       |              3 |    3 |          1 | ghi@example.com | third comment
>  2 | def@example.com | beware of between     |           null | null |       null | null            | null         
>  3 | ghi@example.com | to be or not whatever |              5 |    5 |          3 | ghi@example.com | only comment
> ```

**Grouped Sub-Query** approach (any MySQL version)

> ```
> select
>       a.*
>     , c.*
> from article a
> left join (
>         select
>                c.article_id
>              , max(coalesce((case when c.author <> a.author then c.id end), (case when c.author = a.author then c.id end))) max_comment_id
>         from comments as c 
>         inner join article a on c.article_id = a.id 
>         group by
>                c.article_id
>        ) d on a.id = d.article_id
> left join comments c on d.max_comment_id = c.id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | author          | title                 |   id | article_id | author          | body              
> -: | :-------------- | :-------------------- | ---: | ---------: | :-------------- | :-----------------
>  1 | abc@example.com | a first article       |    4 |          1 | abc@example.com | 2nd author comment
>  2 | def@example.com | beware of between     | null |       null | null            | null              
>  3 | ghi@example.com | to be or not whatever |    5 |          3 | ghi@example.com | only comment
> ```

**Derived Table with row_number()** approach (MySQL 8 onward)

> ```
> select
>       a.*
>     , c.*
> from article a
> left join (
>           select
>                c.*
>              , row_number() over(partition by article_id 
>                                  order by case when c.author <> a.author then 1 else 2 end, id DESC
>                                 ) as rn
>           from comments as c 
>           inner join article a on c.article_id = a.id 
>           ) c on a.id = c.article_id and c.rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | author          | title                 |   id | article_id | author          | body          |   rn
> -: | :-------------- | :-------------------- | ---: | ---------: | :-------------- | :------------ | ---:
>  1 | abc@example.com | a first article       |    3 |          1 | ghi@example.com | third comment |    1
>  2 | def@example.com | beware of between     | null |       null | null            | null          | null
>  3 | ghi@example.com | to be or not whatever |    5 |          3 | ghi@example.com | only comment  |    1
> ```

**Common Table Expression and row_number()** approach (MySQL 8 onward)

> ```
> with max_comments as (
>     select
>            c.*
>          , row_number() over(partition by article_id 
>                              order by case when c.author <> a.author then 1 else 2 end, id DESC
>                             ) as rn
>     from comments as c 
>     inner join article a on c.article_id = a.id 
>     ) 
> select
>       a.*
>     , c.*
> from article a
> left join max_comments c on a.id = c.article_id and c.rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | author          | title                 |   id | article_id | author          | body          |   rn
> -: | :-------------- | :-------------------- | ---: | ---------: | :-------------- | :------------ | ---:
>  1 | abc@example.com | a first article       |    3 |          1 | ghi@example.com | third comment |    1
>  2 | def@example.com | beware of between     | null |       null | null            | null          | null
>  3 | ghi@example.com | to be or not whatever |    5 |          3 | ghi@example.com | only comment  |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9d5ef75109ffc323b50e91473a529f97)*

Comment: by the way, this would be simpler to do using MySQL 8 or in MariaDB because these support `row_number()` - please let me know which database and version you use.

Comment: Are you still requiring a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question, sample join, subquery are not making sense... Having said that, let me try to re-ask your question this way.  If I am correct, great, if not, your question needs some serious clarification thrown at it.

You have this table "T2".  Within it, you have multiple records for any given "dyna_id".  It could have 1 or more records and each "ID" is auto-incremented.  So for a given "Dyna_ID", you want the latest record for that key.  Once you know the latest "ID" for each "Dyna_ID" instance, you want to know who the last person who edited the record was.  To me, this would imply that all records will always have a person who edited the post, unless the first record is the creation record and there is an "addEditor" value and no "LastEditor" value is provided (but don't think this is the case).

So, to get this, it is a two-part query.  First, get the last ID for a given DYNA_ID.  From that, get the name of the LastEditor that matches that given "ID".  Finally, join THAT answer to your other joining to MAIN...

```
INNER JOIN 
   -- getting the Details for that last edited per Dyna_ID
   (select
         T2.Dyna_id,
         T2.ID,
         coalesce( T2.LastEditor, 'abc@example.com' ) as LastEditorPerDynaID
      from
         T2
            -- getting the last ID for any given Dyna_ID
            JOIN ( select
                         tmp1.dyna_id,
                         max(tmp1.id) as MaxIdPerDynaID
                      from
                         t2 tmp1
                      group by 
                         tmp1.dyna_id ) PQ
               on T2.Dyna_ID = PQ.Dyna_ID
              AND T2.ID = PQ.MaxIdPerDynaID ) history 
   ON main.id = history.dyna_id
```

**CLARIFICATION on abc@example.com**

Your requirement of the abc@example.com.  Here is some sample data of the "T2" table.

```
ID   Dyna_ID   LastEditor
 1    A         ME
 2    B         abc@example.com
 3    A         HER
 4    C         ME
 5    B         HIM 
 6    A         abc@example.com
 7    A         HIM
 8    C         HER
 9    B         abc@example.com
10    D         abc@example.com
```

From the above data, I have unique Dyna_ID values of A, B and C, D.  So the max(ID) and ultimate corresponding Last Editor from my original query would result in

```
Dyna_ID  HighestID  LastEditor
A        7          HIM
B        9          abc@example.com
C        8          HER
D        10         abc@example.com
```

So, from this sample data if you were looking ONLY for those where the last editor WAS NOT the abc@example.com, then you want the "B" DynaID to pull the ID=5 LastEditor of "HIM".  But for "D" DynaID, their only record IS the "abc@lexample.com", they have no other, so it is ok to keep that one.

If that is the case, then my inner PQ (Pre-Query) will get the max ID based on EITHER condition respectively of the "abc" entry.  Since we always will have at least one entry, but want the respective max ID with or without...

```
INNER JOIN 
   -- getting the Details for that last edited per Dyna_ID
   (select
         T2.Dyna_id,
         T2.ID,

         coalesce( T2.LastEditor, 'abc@example.com' ) as LastEditorPerDynaID
      from
         T2
            -- getting the last ID for any given Dyna_ID
            JOIN 
            ( select
                    PQ1.Dyna_ID,
                    case when PQ1.MaxIdNotAbcEditor > 0
                         then PQ1.MaxIdNotAbcEditor
                         else PQ1.MaxIdAsAbcEditor end as FinalJoinID
                 from
                    ( select
                            tmp1.dyna_id,
                            -- get max ID if NOT the 'abc' editor
                            max( case when NOT tmp1.LastEditor = 'abc@example.com' then tmp1.id else 0 end ) as MaxIdNotAbcEditor,
                            -- get max ID if IT IS the 'abc' editor
                            max( case when tmp1.LastEditor = 'abc@example.com' then tmp1.id else 0 end ) as MaxIdAsAbcEditor
                         from
                            t2 tmp1
                         group by 
                            tmp1.dyna_id ) PQ1 ) PQ
               on T2.Dyna_ID = PQ.Dyna_ID
              AND T2.ID = PQ.FinalJoinID ) history 
   ON main.id = history.dyna_id
```

Based on the SECOND query, it is a 3-part.  The inner-most "PQ1" prequery 1, for any given Dyna_ID, I am getting the last ID based on EITHER respective part thus

```
Dyna_ID  MaxIdNotAbcEditor   MaxIdAsAbcEditor
A        7                   6
B        5                   9
C        8                   0
D        0                  10
```

As can be seen, DynaID "C" does NOT have an "abc@" record so it's max ID As Abc editor = 0... Inverse for DynaID "D".  It ONLY had an "abc@", so it has 0 for the NOT Abc Editor, and 10 as the AS Abc Editor..  Follow me this far?  Is this correct assumption?

Ok. So now, we have for any single Dyna ID a max possible for either classification.  So now this is wrapped up with the case/when creating the outer "PQ" result of just dyna ID and max id.  If there IS a value for the "I'm not the abc editor" column, use THAT as the ID.  Otherwise grab the only other option... the entry that IS the abc editor.  This results as

```
Dyna_ID   FinalJoinID
A         7
B         5
C         8
D         10
```

Comment: yes that is exactly what i am looking for, but there is a condtion that has to be met,-- I am looking for the latest record for a key where the last editor is not 'abc@example', however if there is no other last editor but 'abc@example for that record, then get 'abc@example.' as the last editor'

Comment: your rep, u are a genius, pleasure to talk to you

Comment: @ManurajSebastian, see the revised answer.  completed clarification and getting based on 'abc' editor requirement or not.